# SQL update using a select case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, case

Having an issue using a 'select case' for a table update.

As a normal select case statement (not updating table) this query works perfectly:

```
select case
    when t1.id in (select t2.id from t2 where [condition1] then 'aaa'
    when t1.id in (select t3.id from t3 where [condition2] then 'bbb'
    when t1.id in (select t4.id from t4 where [condition3] then 'ccc'
    else 'ddd'
end
from owner.t1;
```

However, when i try use the same 'select case' statement in an update statement I get an error stating a subquery returns more than 1 row. This is the update query that does not work:

```
update owner.t1
set t1.var2 =
(select case
    when t1.id in (select t2.id from t2 where [condition1] then 'aaa'
    when t1.id in (select t3.id from t3 where [condition2] then 'bbb'
    when t1.id in (select t4.id from t4 where [condition3] then 'ccc'
    else 'ddd'
end
from owner.t1);
```

When I change the code to below, it works BUT at an incredibly slow rate. Possibly too slow for my purpose.

```
update owner.t1
set t1.var2 =
(select case
    when t2.id in (select t2.id from t2 where [condition1] then 'aaa'
    when t2.id in (select t3.id from t3 where [condition2] then 'bbb'
    when t2.id in (select t4.id from t4 where [condition3] then 'ccc'
    else 'ddd'
end
from owner.t2
where t2.id = t1.id);
```

So my question is why must I reference my id in a secondary table rather than the table that I want to update? And is this extra check in the 'where' statement adding alot of extra time to the operation?

Comment: Your first update query should not throw that error because you are using `IN`. Can you post orginal query

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this?

```
update owner.t1
    set t1.var2 = (case when t1.id in (select t2.id from t2 where [condition1] then 'aaa'
                        when t1.id in (select t3.id from t3 where [condition2] then 'bbb'
                        when t1.id in (select t4.id from t4 where [condition3] then 'ccc'
                        else 'ddd'
                   end);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Gordon. That worked and is alot more eloquent than what I was doing. However, I'm still having time issues but I've figured out that it's just down to the sheer no. of updates.